# How to rename directories using RNFT and RNTO commands? (Python FTP)

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to write a FTP client software in Python. I tried implementing a method to rename directories:

```
 ftp = FTP()
 ftp.connect('host')
 ftp.login('usrname', 'pass')
 ftp.retrlines('RNFR Builds')
 ftp.retrlines('RNTO My_Builds')
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Source.py", line 449, in set_name_from_rename
    self.ftpController.ftp.retrlines('RNFR Builds')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 467, in retrlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 398, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 374, in ntransfercmd
    raise error_reply(resp)
ftplib.error_reply: 350 Directory exists, ready for destination name.
```

I am sure I have the permissions to rename the directory. Can anybody please help? 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `retrlines`, use [`sendcmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.sendcmd). For the final `RNTO`, you can even use [`voidcmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.voidcmd) to validate the operation even more strictly (requires `2xx` response).

```
ftp.sendcmd('RNFR Builds')
ftp.voidcmd('RNTO My_Builds')
```

---

[`retrlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) is used for commands that make use of a data connection. I.e. typically for a directory listing, like `LIST`, `NLST`, `MLSD`. While `RNFR` and `RNTO` are trivial FTP commands that only return status.